# Disable Driverless Printer

Tags: printing, hp, 17.10

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on my desktop.  I have an HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 on the LAN.  Ubuntu keeps adding this printer as a driverless printer but I do not want it added.

I already have this printer using the `hp-setup` command, necessary in order for scanning to work.  In any case, it seems to work much more reliably with the driver.

Is there any way I can prevent Ubuntu from insisting on re-adding the printer.  I do not want to turn of Bonjour on the printer as other people may need it.  I've tried stopping the `cups-browsed` service but this makes no difference.

Comment: Other people may need bonjour? Only if they're using a very old Mac in which case they seriously need to update the OS.

Comment: maybe report this as a bug? That may at least prompt a response from the hard-working ubuntu developers